# Some search result items can't be clicked on

Tags: windows-10, windows-search, search-indexing

windows 10 computer has a problem where clicking on certain search results wouldn't do anything.

Specifically, System setting items like "Reset your PC" wouldn't activate after clicking on them.

If I click on Settings, and navigate there, it works.

Answer (score 1):

Rebuilding the index seemed to to fix the issue.

Control Panel > Indexing options > Advanced > Delete and rebuild index